# Use Facebook Javascript API to log a user out and back in

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, authentication, facebook-javascript-sdk, synchronous

I want a user on my website to click a button that logs them out of Facebook then brings up the login prompt so they can log in again. I am using the Javascript SDK.

I tried calling logout() with login() in the callback. This basically works but pretty much all modern browsers block the login popup. Since logout() is asynchronous, login() isn't handled with the click event.

I have also tried calling logout() followed immediately by login() but not surprisingly, logout() had not taken effect in time. I tried a big for loop between logout and login to try to stall long enough. That didn't work and even if it had it would be prone to errors.

All suggestions for making synchronous Facebook calls are of the sort "you are doing it wrong" But in this particular case this limitation is imposed by the browser and I am not free to change it.

Is there a way to log a user out and then immediately prompt them to log back in? I would like to handle this in Javascript and not redirect to a logout or login page.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this would work but....

Step 1: in your facebook init code, register an event listener for auth.authResponseChange, in which when you detect that response.status==='not_authorized', you set some 'global' js variable as a flag

Step 2:  In the click handler for your button, after the logout call...  use a while loop that waits until that 'global' variable has been set,  and then call FB.login

```
<script>

  //  Create a "global" flag which will be set when the user has logged out
  FB_LOGGED_OUT_FLAG=0;

  window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
  FB.init({
    appId      : 'YOUR_APP_ID', // App ID
    channelUrl : '//WWW.YOUR_DOMAIN.COM/channel.html', // Channel File
    status     : true, // check login status
    cookie     : true, // enable cookies to allow the server to access the session
    xfbml      : true  // parse XFBML
  });

  FB.Event.subscribe('auth.authResponseChange', function(response) {
    if (response.status === 'connected') { FB_LOGGED_OUT_FLAG=0
    } else if (response.status === 'not_authorized') {FB_LOGGED_OUT_FLAG=0
    } else {    //SET YOUR GLOBAL FLAG
        FB_LOGGED_OUT_FLAG =1;

    }
  });
  };

var MY_SWITCH_USER_BUTTON_HANDLER = function(){
  FB.logout();
  while(!FB_USER_LOGGED_OUT_FLAG) {}
  FB.login()
}

  // Load the SDK asynchronously
  (function(d){
   var js, id = 'facebook-jssdk', ref = d.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
   if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
   js = d.createElement('script'); js.id = id; js.async = true;
   js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js";
   ref.parentNode.insertBefore(js, ref);
  }(document));

  }


</script>
```

Not sure if this would lock up the user's machine while the while loop executes..  I'd think not, it would just be executing inside a thread for your page

Comment: This was a good shot but it didn't work. The code hangs on the loop. Since javascript gets a single thread I think the loop hogs that thread and the asynchronous logout call never gets serviced.

Answer (score 0):

How about using jquery to make a synchronous http get request to the facebook logout URL instead of calling FB.login from the SDK..?

See here on making synchronous get requests in jquery...
 [How can I get jQuery to perform a synchronous, rather than asynchronous, Ajax request?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/133310/how-can-i-get-jquery-to-perform-a-synchronous-rather-than-asynchronous-ajax-re)

and try using that approach to do a synchronous get on:

```
https://www.facebook.com/logout.php?access_token=**ACCESS_TOKEN**&next=**REDIRECT**
```

(the redirect might not matter since you're not actually redirecting the user... )

not sure if you're allowed to do a jquery get to a server other than your own..